When reading a Tag on iOS with a link to an associated domain, the app does not open
I am currently making an app which reads and writes specific data to NFC-Tags via Ndef. I would like to add the functionality to the app, that when a corresponding tag is read, it should open the app. I am using react-native to create this app, if this matters.
I have read about associated domains and have setup said feature in Xcode and on the iOS device used for developing the app. The associated domains diagnostic feature from iOS tells me that my setup on the server side of things seems to be correct and it should actually open my app(via team id and app id) but it doesn't.
In Xcode I have added the domain like this applinks:example.com?mode=developer (without http or https) in the associated domains tab.
The content of my apple-app-site-association file  looks like this. its located in root dir but there is also a copy in /.well_known/
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "TEAMID.bundleIdentifier" ],
         "paths": [
        "*"
         ]
           }
       ]
   }
}

the url on the url record of the tag looks like this: http://example.com
I am wondering if my app needs to implement some sort of handling function for this to work but if so, I am not quite sure about the correct way of doing this with react native running on top.

Look into the iPhone app Shortcuts. This application is somewhat the same with your project. Shortcuts can also do an action when a certain nfc card is scanned.

Enter the url in safari and see if it opens your app. You mention the "associated domains diagnostic feature" - are you referring to the developer menu on the device?  You will need to implement a function in your app delegate to handle the incoming url

yes I meant the function in the developer menu on the device. if I open the url in safari, the app does not open, which then means I need to implement a handling function? thanks!
